# Include model SequelizeJS

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I get an error when I try to include a model on an "findAll" action using SequelizeJS...

```
    Executing (default): SELECT `projects`.*, `Medias`.`id` AS `Medias.id`, `Medias`.`title` AS `Medias.title`, `Medias`.`image` AS `Medias.image`, `Medias`.`createdAt` AS `Medias.createdAt`, `Medias`.`updatedAt` AS `Medias.updatedAt`, `Medias`.`projectId` AS `Medias.projectId` FROM `projects` LEFT OUTER JOIN `media` AS `Medias` ON `projects`.`id` = `Medias`.`projectId` ORDER BY id DESC;

    TypeError: Cannot call method 'hasOwnProperty' of null
        at Function.Dot.transform (/Users/anthonycluse/Sites/Sbaf/Back-End/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/dottie/dottie.js:102:50)
        at /Users/anthonycluse/Sites/Sbaf/Back-End/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query.js:366:17
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at module.exports.groupJoinData (/Users/anthonycluse/Sites/Sbaf/Back-End/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query.js:365:10)
        at module.exports.handleSelectQuery (/Users/anthonycluse/Sites/Sbaf/Back-End/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query.js:233:17)
        at module.exports.AbstractQuery.formatResults (/Users/anthonycluse/Sites/Sbaf/Back-End/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query.js:70:34)
        at null.<anonymous> (/Users/anthonycluse/Sites/Sbaf/Back-End/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:33:35)
        at Query.Sequence.end (/Users/anthonycluse/Sites/Sbaf/Back-End/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:78:24)
        aMacBook-Pro-de-Anthony:Back-End anthonycluse$
```

My action :

```
dbContext.project.findAll({order: 'id DESC', include: [{model: dbContext.media, as: 'Medias'}]}).success(function(projects) {
        callback(projects);
});
```

My dbContext :

```
(function () {

    var modelsPath = __dirname + '/../app/models/';

    /**
    * Constructor.
    * Add your entities 'DbSet' instance here like user.
    */
    function DbContext() {
        this.db = require('./dbConnection');
        this.entities();
        this.modelBuilder();
    }

    /**
     * Attach your model to DbContext like user to perform database sync.
     * 
     */
    DbContext.prototype.entities = function() {
        this.project = this.db.import(modelsPath + 'project');
        this.media = this.db.import(modelsPath + 'media');
    };

    /**
    * Manage Database entities associations here.
    */
    DbContext.prototype.modelBuilder = function () {
        this.project.hasMany(this.media, {as: 'Medias'});
        this.media.belongsTo(this.project);
    };

    module.exports = DbContext;
})();
```

Comment: Your error in dottie.js, sequelize js work is fine(i see valid SQL query)

Comment: Ok and what am I supposed to do? to fix this error...

Comment: Did you try to use 'projects.id DESC' in the order attribute value?

Comment: Your 'order' attribute should be like this. order: [['id', 'DESC']]

Comment: Your order attribute in findAll function should be like this: order:[['id', 'DESC']]